# Threading to allow a canvas animation run while behind the scenes processing

Tags: python, multithreading, animation

I am trying to create an animated popup (right now just using a sample of moving bubbles - but will change to a "loading" animation of some sort).  I have a main class that asks for a directory and then it creates directory objects for each image file in the directory.  This takes a bit of time (as I load the EXIF data), and I wanted to put up a popup to indicate it is processing.

I am trying to use threading, and it does create the popup, but it doesn't run the loop.

Help on what I am doing wrong would be appreciated.

I originally ran the program without threading and it hung.  So I added the threading and it now creates the popup, but does not run the loop to animate the bubbles.

Main.py

```
import tkinter as tk
import customtkinter as ctk
from utilities import *
from CTkTable import CTkTable
from test import BubbleFrame



class App(ctk.CTk):
        def __init__(self):
                                
                # setup
                super().__init__()
                ctk.set_appearance_mode('light')
                self.geometry('1000x600')
                self.title('Media Management')
                self.resizable(0,0)

                self.top_frame = ctk.CTkFrame(master=self, fg_color="#bb22d6",  width=600, height=100, corner_radius=0)
                self.top_frame.pack_propagate(0)
                self.top_frame.pack(fill="x", anchor="n", side="top")



                self.path_string = ctk.StringVar()

                ctk.CTkButton(
                        master=self.top_frame, 
                        text="Open Directory", 
                        fg_color="#fff", 
                        font=("Arial Bold", 14), 
                        text_color="#2A8C55", 
                        hover_color="#eee", 
                        anchor="center",
                        command=lambda: open_file_dialog(self, self.top_frame, load_spinner_popup)
                        ).pack(
                                anchor="w", 
                                ipady=(5),
                                padx=(10),
                                pady=(10)
                                )

                ctk.CTkEntry(
                        master=self.top_frame,
                        textvariable = self.path_string,
                        font=("Arial Bold", 12), 
                        text_color="#2A8C55",
                        width= 400
                        ).pack(
                                expand = True,
                                fill = 'y',
                                anchor = 'w',
                                padx = 10, 
                                pady = 10)
        

                def load_spinner_popup(self, top_frame):
                        top= tk.Toplevel(top_frame)
                        top.geometry("750x250")
                        top.title("Loading Files")
                        bubbles = BubbleFrame(top)
                        bubbles.loop(top)
                        #tk.Label(top, text= "Loading Files!", font=('Mistral 18 bold')).place(x=150,y=80)
                        return(top)     


                #run
                self.mainloop()


       
App()
```

utilities.py

```
from dbconnection import *
from datetime import datetime as dt
import os
from tkinter import filedialog
from pathlib import Path
from CTkTable import CTkTable
import customtkinter as ctk
import exiftool
from imagefile import ImageFile
import tkinter as tk
import threading




# function: open_file_dialog
# opens the file dialog pop-up to select a directory and sets the path_string variable
def open_file_dialog(self, top_frame, load_spinner_popup):
    self.path_string.set(filedialog.askdirectory())
    top = threading.Thread(target=load_spinner_popup(self, top_frame)).start()
    self.update()
    self.image_table = load_img_table(self, top)


def load_img_table(self, top):

    self.file_table_frame = ctk.CTkFrame(master=self, fg_color="#bb22d6",  width=600, height=300, corner_radius=0, border_color="#FFF", border_width=5)
    self.file_table_frame.pack_propagate(0)
    self.file_table_frame.pack(fill="x", anchor="n", side="top")


    self.image_list = get_dir_of_imgs(self.path_string)


    self.table_frame = ctk.CTkScrollableFrame(master=self.file_table_frame, fg_color="transparent")
    self.table_frame.pack(expand=True, fill="both", padx=27, pady=21)

    self.table = CTkTable(master=self.table_frame, values=self.image_list, colors=["#E6E6E6", "#EEEEEE"], header_color="#2A8C55", hover_color="#B4B4B4")
    self.table.edit_row(0, text_color="#fff", hover_color="#2A8C55")
    self.table.pack(expand=True)

    close_spinner_popup(top)

def get_dir_of_imgs(path_string):
    image_list = [['Image Name', 'Image Type', 'Created Date', 'Location']]
    images = Path(path_string.get()).glob("*.jpg")
    for image in images:
        img_file = ImageFile(image)
        createDate = img_file.createDate
        address = img_file.address
        image_list.append([image.name, image.suffix, createDate, address])
    return(image_list)

def get_exif_data(path):
    with exiftool.ExifTool() as et:
        files = [path]
        metadata = et.get_metadata_batch(files)
    return(metadata)


def close_spinner_popup(top):
    top.destroy()
```

test.py

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

class BubbleFrame:

    def __init__(self, root):
        root.title("Math Bubbles")
        #tk.Button(root, text="Add Bubbles", width=8, command=self.bubble).pack()
        tk.Button(root, text="Quit", width=8, command=quit).pack()
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=800, height=650, bg = '#afeeee')
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.bubbles = {} # this will hold bubbles ids, positions and velocities
        self.bubble() 

    def bubble(self):
        # add bubbles for numbers from 1 to 20
        for number in range(1, 20+1):
            xval = random.randint(5,765)
            yval = random.randint(5,615)
            s1 = self.canvas.create_oval(xval,yval,xval+30,yval+30, fill="#00ffff",outline="#00bfff",width=5)
            s2 = self.canvas.create_text(xval+15,yval+15, text=number)
            self.bubbles[(s1, s2)] = (xval, yval, 0, 0) # add bubbles to dictionary

    def loop(self, root):
        for (s1, s2), (x, y, dx, dy) in self.bubbles.items():
            # update velocities and positions
            dx += random.randint(-1, 1)
            dy += random.randint(-1, 1)
            # dx and dy should not be too large
            dx, dy = max(-5, min(dx, 5)), max(-5, min(dy, 5))
            # bounce off walls
            if not 0 < x < 770: dx = -dx
            if not 0 < y < 620: dy = -dy
            # apply new velocities
            self.canvas.move(s1, dx, dy)
            self.canvas.move(s2, dx, dy)
            self.bubbles[(s1, s2)] = (x + dx, y + dy, dx, dy)
        # have mainloop repeat this after 100 ms
        root.after(100, self.loop, root)

#if __name__ == "__main__":
#    root = tk.Tk()
#    frame = BubbleFrame(root)
#    frame.loop(root)
#    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: (1) You are calling `load_spinner_popup` (appending parentheses) and set the result as `target` function of the thread. Instead the target should be the function itself (2) Calling tkinter functions in a thread other than the main one may produce unexpected results.

Comment: Ok...so I updated the code to be:     top = threading.Thread(target=load_spinner_popup, args=(self, top_frame)).start()

Still doesn't work.

As to your point 2...if that is the case, what is the best (accepted) means of having a popup to indicate a long running process?

Comment: Collect the data using `get_dir_of_imgs` and `get_exif_data` in another thread (while showing the bubbles from the main thread). When data is collected, call `root.after` from the other thread (the `after` method should be rather thread-safe) to execute a method similar to `load_img_table` to build the table and close the animation popup.